# code to destroy zend session gets executed although its not allowed by if else and switch case conditions

Tags: zend-framework, session

```
$getId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); // 1 is coming from url
$id_from_cart = 1; 

if($getId != $id_from_cart) {    
    echo "unset session";    
    Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('cart'); 
} else {  
    echo "dont unset"; 
}
```

When I use $getId = 1 as a static value, its working fine but if I use $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') as its value which is also 1 then although it goes in else condition in both the cases but it unsets the session (code written in if condition). How is that possible, code to destroy session has been written in if condition. I have tried  many things but couldn't reach anywhere. Any suggestion could be a great help. I have tried switch case, in_array and if else.

Comment: please post the complete controller action

Comment: public function informationAction()
{
  $this->view->restaurant_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
  $id_from_cart = Helper_common::getRestaurantIdFromCart();
  if(!empty($emptyObject) && ($this->view->restaurant_id != $id_from_cart)){
      Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('cart');
    }

}
@ArneRie

Comment: I have just executed the same code using ajax, it is working. $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') is working with ajax but not on page load.
@ArneRie

Comment: whats the sense of "emptyobject" in your if statement?

Comment: $cart = new Zend_Session_Namespace('cart');
     $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
     $emptyObject = (array)$cart->cart_items;
its just the variable , i have converted the object into array and stored in it. Sorry, i forgot to mention that code in my previous comment @ArneRie

Comment: if it works via ajax it will work via regular php, you just have to locate where the session(or other variable) is being reset. It's a common problem in ZF the variables get reset accidentally due to a new request being sent. One of your variables is not what you expect it to be. Dump em all and see what's what.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$getId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```